# How can I condense multiple SELECT statements into one when the value is based on the value in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

From the front end, XML is sent to a stored procedure which parses it out into a temporary table with two columns:

```
 | DataName | DataValue |
1| blahblah | datadata  |
2|    ...   |    ...    |
3|    ...   |    ...    |
4|    ...   |    ...    |
```

From this temporary table, I am setting the value in the DataValue column to a variable based on the string in the DataName column. For Example:

```
SELECT @blahblah= IsNull(DataValue,0)
        FROM #XMLTempTable
        WHERE DataName = 'blahblah'

SELECT @userid = IsNull(DataValue,0)
        FROM #XMLTempTable
        WHERE DataName = 'userid'

SELECT @value = IsNull(DataValue,0)
        FROM #XMLTempTable
        WHERE DataName = 'value'
```

Is there a better way I can be selecting the values out of the temporary table, rather than one at a time as I am doing?

Comment: do you also need to form rows, each row containing [userid], [value], [blahblah] ?  is the row order of the xml important?

Comment: @Used_By_Already Row order is not important here, just trying to see if there is a better way of pulling data out of the XML than making a ton of select statements to the same temp table (if the result set becomes large).

Comment: why then are you placing data into scalar values?  (@blahblah  is "scalar" )

Comment: I have to update other data/tables conditionally based on some of the values within the XML, so I'm pulling out what I need & using IF blocks to update from there. (Im pretty new to SQL so if this sounds like a horrible idea, please let me know lol)

Comment: In general approaching SQL as if it is a typical programming language is a bad idea. I have added a possible answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `CASE WHEN .. END`

```
SELECT @blahblah = CASE WHEN  DataName = 'blahblah' THEN IsNull(DataValue,0) ELSE 0 END, 
       @userid = CASE WHEN  DataName = 'userid' THEN IsNull(DataValue,0) ELSE 0 END, 
       @value = CASE WHEN  DataName = 'value' THEN IsNull(DataValue,0) ELSE 0 END
FROM #XMLTempTable
WHERE DataName in ('blahblah', 'userid', 'value')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are attempting to "pivot" these key/value pairs into more meaningful rows then perhaps this will help you. However please do note that assuming any order of rows in a sql table is a bad idea, despite this the following makes this assumption.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE #XMLTempTable(
>    ID INT  NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
>   ,DataName  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
>   ,DataValue VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
> );
> INSERT INTO #XMLTempTable(DataName,DataValue) VALUES ('blahblah','blah-1');
> INSERT INTO #XMLTempTable(DataName,DataValue) VALUES ('userid','user-1');
> INSERT INTO #XMLTempTable(DataName,DataValue) VALUES ('value','value-1');
> INSERT INTO #XMLTempTable(DataName,DataValue) VALUES ('blahblah','blah-2');
> INSERT INTO #XMLTempTable(DataName,DataValue) VALUES ('userid','user-2');
> INSERT INTO #XMLTempTable(DataName,DataValue) VALUES ('value','value-2');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   id
> , blahblah = CASE WHEN  DataName = 'blahblah' THEN datavalue END
> , userid = CASE WHEN  DataName = 'userid' THEN DataValue END
> , value = CASE WHEN  DataName = 'value' THEN DataValue END
> FROM #XMLTempTable
> WHERE DataName in ('blahblah', 'userid', 'value')
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | blahblah | userid | value  
> -: | :------- | :----- | :------
>  1 | blah-1   | null   | null   
>  2 | null     | user-1 | null   
>  3 | null     | null   | value-1
>  4 | blah-2   | null   | null   
>  5 | null     | user-2 | null   
>  6 | null     | null   | value-2
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   (id + 2) / 3 as rowno
> , max(CASE WHEN  DataName = 'blahblah' THEN datavalue END) as blahblah
> , max(CASE WHEN  DataName = 'userid' THEN DataValue END) as userid
> , max(CASE WHEN  DataName = 'value' THEN DataValue END) as datavalue
> FROM #XMLTempTable
> WHERE DataName in ('blahblah', 'userid', 'value')
> GROUP BY
>   (id + 2) / 3
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> rowno | blahblah | userid | datavalue
> ----: | :------- | :----- | :--------
>     1 | blah-1   | user-1 | value-1  
>     2 | blah-2   | user-2 | value-2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6c453f21eaebba6c55c52b95a42880a1)*

Answer (score 1):

If you have privilege to create functions, you may also consider implementing the logic in such a way to make the code consistent, reusable and shareable. This approach is handy for data analysts or departmental DBAs who are required to frequently perform common data cleansing logics.

**Test dataset**

```
use [testdb];
if OBJECT_ID('testdb..test') is not null
    drop table testdb..test;

create table test (
    DataName varchar(50),
    DataValue varchar(50),
);

insert into test (DataName, DataValue)
values ('name1', NULL),('name2', NULL),('name3', NULL);

select * from test;
GO
```

**Put your logic into a reusable function**

```
if OBJECT_ID('testdb.dbo.myfunc', 'FN') is not null
    drop function myfunc;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.myfunc(@param varchar(100))  
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN  
    -- implement your logic here
    declare @ret varchar(max);

    if @param = 'name1'
        set @ret = @param + '_logic1';
    else if @param = 'name2'
        set @ret = @param + '_logic2';
    else if @param = 'name3'
        set @ret = @param + '_logic3';

    return @ret;
END
GO
```

**Execute**

```
update A
    set A.DataValue = dbo.myfunc(A.DataName)
    from test as A;

select * from test;
-- DataName  DataValue
-- name1     name1_logic1
-- name2     name2_logic2
-- name3     name3_logic3
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the ability to create my own functions here, but I appreciate the time you took to answer my question! I'll keep this in mind for the future.